# Sort array of objects according to another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I want to sort the javascript object in order of another object that have keys and sorting order

I have an object let say

```
sectionSorting = {
      "metrics": "12",
      "details": "3",
      "portfolio": "5"
      "backetst":"14"
}
```

I have another object like

```
sections = {
      backtest: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
      metrics: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
      details: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
      methodology: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
      portfoolio: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}]
}
```

Now I want to sort the 'sections' object in the sorting order of 'sectionSorting' object.
The feilds which do not have sorting order will remail in last.

The desired Output I need is,

```
sortedSections = {
   details: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
   portfoolio: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
   metrics: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
   backtest: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
   methodology: [{key: "abc", value: "xyz"}],
}
```

I can not figure out how to do that
Can Anybody help me ?

Comment: Why sort an object? you access values of object by keys.

Comment: I want to show values of object in order that user decides

Comment: [using property order for fundamental program logic probably isn't a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/17447)

Comment: You cannot really gaurantee order of the keys in an Object. Its a map. Either keep a separate copy (which you already have "sectionSorting") - and use it for parsing OR create an array of objects

Comment: @SrushtiShah object in JavaScript is not designed for this, if you want things to be shown in order, use an array to setup the order, and output results by a for...of loop of that say array to access the object values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really gaurantee order of the keys in an Object. Its a map.

**Option 1**

Either keep a separate copy (which you already have "sectionSorting") - and use it for parsing and showing it to the user

**Option 2**
create an array of objects like this:

```
[{
        "type": "details",
        "key": "abc",
        "value": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "type": "portfolio",
        "key": "abc",
        "value": "xyz"
    }, {
        "type": "metrics",
        "key": "abc",
        "value": "xyz"
    }, {
        "type": "backtest",
        "key": "abc",
        "value": "xyz"
    }, {
        "type": "methodology",
        "key": "abc",
        "value": "xyz"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

An object is an unordered collection, so I think there is nothing call "sorting an oject keys"