# Sorting Keys and Values of an Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

How do i sort this object
here is my code

```
const player = {"Bong":"henry","rj":"ken","Robert":"dj","Brad":"jeff" }
Object.entries(player).sort(([k,v]) => {
    if(k < v){
        return -1
    }
    if(k > v){
        return 1
    }
    return 0
})
```

my Expected output should be:

```
{"Bong":"dj","Brad":"henry","rj":"jeff","Robert":"ken"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects according to another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74514272/sort-array-of-objects-according-to-another-object)

Comment: @SrushtiShah It's not an array of objects, it's a single object.

Comment: There is no point of sorting the object as it can be accessed by keys. You can convert this object to array of objects and then sort it